# Spring 4 force property to be defined

Tags: java, spring

In spring I can retrieve property(defined in properties file) using `getProperty` method(of Environment) E.g.

```
@PropertySource("classpath:app.properties")
public class Config{
    @Autowired
    Environment env;

@Bean 
public Foo foo(){
 env.getProperty("foo.isEligible")
//.... return foo.
}
}
```

however if the property is not defined then  it returns `null`. We could make a null check and throw exception explicitly but is there some built-in method in spring to achieve it, so that application will throw exception if the property requested via `getProperty` method is not defined  . I am using spring 4.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getRequiredProperty` which throws IllegalStateException if property is undefined. E.g.

```
env.getRequiredProperty("foo");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want an error at Spring startup time, if you used something like

```
@Value("${foo.isEligible}")
protected boolean isFooEligible;
```

The Spring `ApplicationContext` will fail to startup if it can't resolve this SpEL expression